# Offset every 5th row in excel after concatenate

Tags: excel, concatenation, offset

I am trying to concatenate two cells within the same column but then update the first concatenate part with the 5th cell down. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
[Column A]  
Developer  
senior  
mid  
junior  
apprentice  
Analyst  
senior  
mid  
junior  
apprentice  
Business  
senior  
mid  
junior  
apprentice
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

```
[Column B]  
Developer-senior  
Developer-mid  
Developer-junior  
Developer-apprentice  
Analyst-senior  
Analyst-mid  
Analyst-junior  
Analyst-apprentice  
Business...
```

I've tried to concatenate and use offset but no luck. Here is my code: `=OFFSET(A$1,(ROW()-1)*5,0)` 
which will grab Developer, Analyst, and Business. But I am not sure where to go from here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Always the same amount of sub positions?

Comment: Yes, it's always the fourth cell down

Comment: This seems like a senseless task unless it is a skill test?

Comment: Not a skills test. I'm trying to re-organize my excel sheet. Originally I had the career level for each position underneath the title, but now I would like to have title and career level in the same row.

Comment: Easier ways about going about it. hold tight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `INDEX` function:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$15,INT((ROW()-1)/5)*5+1) & "-" & IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$15,IF((ROW()-1)/5-INT((ROW()-1)/5)<>0,ROW(),-1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarification in the comments, put these in your spreadsheet, starting on `B2`.

- Select `B1:B5` then copy them down.
- Copy `B:B` and paste value
- Go to the Data tab, select the column, then remove duplicates.

---

```
=TRIM(A1)&"-"&A2
=TRIM(A1)&"-"&A3
=TRIM(A1)&"-"&A4
=TRIM(A1)&"-"&A5
```